How to remove the square border coming in Balloon callout in ArcGIS Pro SDK
I have written C# code in ArcGIS Pro SDK for balloon callout and everything works fine. The only issue is I am getting square border between the points. How can I disable it?
if (geometry is Polyline polyline)
 {
     var startPoint = polyline.Points.FirstOrDefault();
     var endPoint = polyline.Points.LastOrDefault();
     if (startPoint != null && endPoint != null)
     {
         var graphicsLayer = MapView.Active.Map.TargetGraphicsLayer;

         var textSymbol = await CreateBalloonCalloutAsync(ColorFactory.Instance.BlackRGB);
         var textGraphic = new CIMTextGraphic()
         {
             Text = "X:" + Math.Round(startPoint.X, 2) + ",Y:" + Math.Round(startPoint.Y, 2),
             Placement = Anchor.CenterPoint,
             Symbol = textSymbol.MakeSymbolReference(),
             Shape = endPoint,
             Leaders = new CIMLeader[]
             {
                new CIMLeaderPoint()
                {
                  //for a graphics layer, the leader location is in map coords
                  Point = startPoint
                }
             }
         };
         await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
         {
             graphicsLayer.AddElement(textGraphic);
         });
     }
 }

    private static Task<CIMTextSymbol> CreateBalloonCalloutAsync(CIMColor textColor)
      {
          return QueuedTask.Run<CIMTextSymbol>(() =>
          {
              //create a text symbol
              var textSymbol = SymbolFactory.Instance.ConstructTextSymbol(textColor, 11, "Arial", "Regular");
              //A balloon callout
              var balloonCallout = new CIMBalloonCallout();
              //set the callout's style
              balloonCallout.BalloonStyle = BalloonCalloutStyle.RoundedRectangle;
              //Create a solid fill polygon symbol for the callout.
              var polySymbol = SymbolFactory.Instance.ConstructPolygonSymbol(ColorFactory.Instance.CreateRGBColor(255, 255, 0), SimpleFillStyle.Solid);
              //Set the callout's background to be the black polygon symbol
              balloonCallout.BackgroundSymbol = polySymbol;
              //margin inside the callout to place the text
              balloonCallout.Margin = new CIMTextMargin
              {
                  Left = 2.5,
                  Right = 2.5,
                  Bottom = 2,
                  Top = 2
              };
              balloonCallout.LeaderOffset = 10;
              balloonCallout.LeaderTolerance = 25;
              //assign the callout to the text symbol's callout property
              textSymbol.Callout = balloonCallout;
              return textSymbol;
          });
      }

